# Trumpet range inconsistent

Tags: exercises, trumpet

Okay so I'm a high level saxophone player who recently picked up trumpet.

To natural air support and musical knowledge I've been fairly comfortable with range. One day I suddendly clicked and I was able to consistently hit an High E above the staff with zero tension using air support and tongue arch. Then today I pick up my horn and I've lost all of that and my range got worse than before and I can't seem to get what was before is there anything I can to try and get my body to remember what I did?

Comment: When you say High E above the staff do you mean E on the third ledger line above the staff?  Or E in the top space of the staff?

Answer (score 2):

This might be something that needs checking in person, but two common pitfalls are:

1. Pressing the mouthpiece against your upper lip to get higher notes. It will work but it will sound pinched and could be pretty painful. It's also terrible practice and very limiting.
2. Using "mouth shapes" to get higher notes. You mention "tongue arch", but in playing the trumpet tongue arch is very … controversial. Some people will swear by it, others swear at you for using it. But at the end of the day, good embouchure is really the only way to get consistent, clean notes, every time. That may include "tongue arch" for you.

As for why one time and not the next, I would suspect experience and muscle strength. "High" notes require a lot of support from your lips, throat, and diaphragm. If you're just learning, it's easy for one of those to get all out of whack and throw you off your game. Especially throat muscles that you don't really "feel".

And cheeks, don't forget cheeks. It's easy to forget cheeks.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem basic but make sure your lips aren't dry. Dry lips can limit you from playing a lot which could be the reason behind your problem. If you are playing frequently try to keep Vaseline with you, especially when it is cold outside as moisture on your lips will easily dry them out.